# Find SQL rows associated to other using 1:1 linking tables and CTE (eg. permissions on users and groups)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, common-table-expression

### The problem

I need to determine if an user `U` can access an entity `E` according to permissions stored in MySQL tables (on MariaDB 10.2) with the following rules:

- permissions can be given to users and to groups.
- permissions are only *allow*: the existence of a relation between an entity and a user/group means it (the user or the group) is allowed to access the entity.
- groups membership: an user can be part of one or more groups.
- groups inheritance: a group can have a parent group, the permissions of parent group applies to children groups.

The tables are already in place and the way I understand my problem it falls down to:
"Is there a *link* between the row of user `U` and the row of entity `E` (via any possible path)?"

Because the tables are no graphs (see details below) and because of groups inheritance I think I can use Common Table Expressions here (which I am not familiar with), with recursion (even worse for me).

### My attempt

So I built the following SQL query to support direct entity-user allowance (first CTE: `cte_entities_allowed_to_users`)

```sql
SET @TEST_EID = 302;
SET @TEST_UID = 103;

WITH
cte_entities_allowed_to_users AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        entities.eid,
        entity_user_access.uid
    FROM
        entity_user_access
        JOIN entities
            ON entity_user_access.eid = entities.eid
)
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    cte_entities_allowed_to_users
WHERE
    cte_entities_allowed_to_users.eid = @TEST_EID
    AND cte_entities_allowed_to_users.uid = @TEST_UID
```

And also built the following other CTE:

```sql
cte_groups_of_users AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        users.uid,
        groups.gid
    FROM
        groups
        JOIN group_members
            ON group_members.gid = groups.gid
        JOIN users
            ON users.uid = group_members.uid
)
,
cte_entities_allowed_to_groups AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        entities.eid,
        entity_group_access.gid
    FROM
        entity_group_access
        JOIN entities
            ON entity_group_access.eid = entities.eid
)
```

### Where I struggle

But I am not sure:

- how to use them altogether
- nor how to build the other CTE (mostly the one using `group_of_groups` table)
- nor if CTEs are the way to go for this kind of problem

### What I expect ("truth table")

For the following `@TEST_EID` and `@TEST_UID` pairs here are the expected returned value for the SELECT (the `COUNT(*)` field)):

| `@TEST_EID` | `@TEST_UID` | Return | Why |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | 101 | ≥1 | `entity_user_access` has a `(301,101)` row |
| 301 | 102 | ≥1 | `entity_user_access` has a `(301,102)` row |
| 301 | 103 | =0 |  |
| 302 | 101 | =0 |  |
| 302 | 102 | ≥1 | `entity_group_access` has a `(302,201)` row and `group_members` has a `(201,102)` row |
| 302 | 103 | ≥1 | `entity_user_access` has a `(302,103)` row |
| 303 | 101 | =0 |  |
| 303 | 102 | ≥1 | `(303,201)` row in `entity_group_access` and `group_members` has a `(201,102)` row |
| 303 | 103 | ≥1 | `entity_user_access` has a `(303,103)` row |
| 304 | 101 | ≥1 | `(304,205)` row in `entity_group_access` and `group_of_groups` has a`(204,205)` row and `group_members` has a `(204,101)` row |
| 304 | 102 | ≥1 | `(304,201)` row in `entity_group_access` and `group_members` has a `(201,102)` row |
| 304 | 103 | ≥1 | `(304,205)` row in `entity_group_access` and `group_of_groups` has a`(202,205)` row and `group_members` has a `(202,103)` row |

### Annex 1/1: Tables details

Relations:

```
      [users]───────────────[group_members]─────[groups]──┐
         │                       │                 │      │
         │                       │                 └──[group_of_groups]
[entity_user_access]   [entity_group_access]
         │                       │
         └────────┐    ┌─────────┘
                  │    │
                [entities]
```

Some example dataset:

`users` table:

| uid | uname |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Alice |
| 102 | Bob |
| 103 | Charlie |

`groups` table:

| gid | gname |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | Administrators |
| 202 | Users |
| 203 | Operators |
| 204 | Guests |
| 205 | X-Mas event |

`entities` table:

| eid | ename |
| --- | --- |
| 301 | Foo |
| 302 | Bar |
| 303 | Qux |
| 304 | Snow |

`entity_user_access` table:

| eid | uid |
| --- | --- |
| 301 | 101 |
| 301 | 102 |
| 302 | 103 |
| 303 | 103 |

`entity_group_access` table:

| eid | gid |
| --- | --- |
| 301 | 201 |
| 302 | 201 |
| 303 | 201 |
| 304 | 201 |
| 302 | 203 |
| 304 | 205 |

`group_members` table:

| gid | uid | Comment (not part of data) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 102 | Bob is an admin |
| 203 | 102 | Bob is also an operator |
| 202 | 103 | Charlie is an user |
| 204 | 101 | Alice is a guest |

`group_of_groups` table:

| gid | parent_gid | Comment (not part of data) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 203 | Admins (201) are Operators (203) |
| 202 | 205 | Users (202) are in the X-Mas event group (205) |
| 204 | 205 | Guests (204) are in the X-Mas event group (205) |

Full SQL:

```sql
-- Structure
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `uid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `uname` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
);
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
    `gid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `gname` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`gid`)
);
CREATE TABLE `entities` (
    `eid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `ename` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`eid`)
);
CREATE TABLE `entity_user_access` (
    `eid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `uid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`eid`, `uid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_eua_entity` FOREIGN KEY (`eid`) REFERENCES `entities` (`eid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_eua_user` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `users` (`uid`)
);
CREATE TABLE `entity_group_access` (
    `eid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `gid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`eid`, `gid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_ega_entity` FOREIGN KEY (`eid`) REFERENCES `entities` (`eid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_ega_group` FOREIGN KEY (`gid`) REFERENCES `groups` (`gid`)
);
CREATE TABLE `group_members` (
    `gid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `uid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`gid`, `uid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_gm_group` FOREIGN KEY (`gid`) REFERENCES `groups` (`gid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_gm_user` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `users` (`uid`)
);
CREATE TABLE `group_of_groups` (
    `gid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `parent_gid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`gid`, `parent_gid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_gog_group` FOREIGN KEY (`gid`) REFERENCES `groups` (`gid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_gog_parent_group` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_gid`) REFERENCES `groups` (`gid`)
);

-- Data
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES
    (101, 'Alice'),
    (102, 'Bob'),
    (103, 'Charlie');
INSERT INTO `groups` VALUES
    (201, 'Administrators'),
    (202, 'Users'),
    (203, 'Operators'),
    (204, 'Guests'),
    (205, 'X-Mas event');
INSERT INTO `entities` VALUES
    (301, 'Foo'),
    (302, 'Bar'),
    (303, 'Qux'),
    (304, 'Snow');
INSERT INTO `entity_user_access` VALUES
    (301, 101),
    (301, 102),
    (302, 103),
    (303, 103);
INSERT INTO `entity_group_access` VALUES
    (301, 201),
    (302, 201),
    (302, 203),
    (303, 201),
    (304, 201),
    (304, 205);
INSERT INTO `group_members` VALUES
    (201, 102),
    (202, 103),
    (203, 102),
    (204, 101);
INSERT INTO `group_of_groups` VALUES
    (201, 203),
    (202, 205),
    (204, 205);
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IFNULL(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, 1) */;
```

Comment: can you add the result ypou expect

Comment: You are right, it was missing: done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTE are only a replcament for subqueries.

But your idea how to handle it is a bit off

Your groups table needs to have the same strucure like your first, so you must join the other tables as well to get eid and uid

The next step is to `UNION` the results so that they are joined verticcally

on that union you run your count query

See example

> ```
> SET @TEST_EID = 302;
> SET @TEST_UID = 103;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*)
> FROM
> (    SELECT
>         DISTINCT
>         entities.eid,
>         entity_user_access.uid
>     FROM
>         entity_user_access
>         JOIN entities
>             ON entity_user_access.eid = entities.eid
> UNION
>     SELECT
>         DISTINCT
>         entities.eid,
>         users.uid
>     FROM
>         `groups`
>         JOIN group_members
>             ON group_members.gid = groups.gid
>         JOIN users
>             ON users.uid = group_members.uid
>          JOIN 
>             entity_group_access
>             ON groups.gid = entity_group_access.gid
>          JOIN entities
>             ON entity_group_access.eid = entities.eid) t1
> WHERE eid = @TEST_EID and uid = @TEST_UID
> ```
>
> ```
> | COUNT(*) |
> | -------: |
> |        1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=912ed777c3c600611284b65af0b18fa2)*